# Postgres one-liner import & export SQL without login & without asked for password

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for one-liner command for import & export SQL without login into postgres role or psql prompt.

Below is what I got for import SQL, but it asking password every time:

```
psql -h localhost -d dbname -U postgres -f /var/www/db.sql
```

Below is equivalent command in MySQL (import & export):

```
mysql -u root -p password dbname < /var/www/db.sql

mysqldump -u root -p password --single-transaction --skip-extended-insert --quick dbname > /var/www/db.sql
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6405127/330315

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15359348/939860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`psql` doesn't provide a command line option for the password to avoid disclosing it to other local users.

However it accepts the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable, so your equivalent of mysql's `-p password` is, in shell syntax:

```
PGPASSWORD=password psql -h localhost -d dbname -U postgres -f /var/www/db.sql
```

Alternatively, a client-side [password file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) may be used.